# Attempting to get BitBucket and Teamcity to work

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket

I have a build machine set up and I am able to get code from Bitbucket just fine from the command prompt.

In teamcity,  I get the following

Updating sources: agent side checkout (1s)
[17:14:42][Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to run git at path git.exe

I tried updating the path , changing repository settings and I am able to do everything at command prompt from the same user as Teamcity uses on the build machine.

Its a windows build machine.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of your VCS Root configuration in TeamCity, full error log, etc.?

Comment: Are you sure you have `git.exe` in `%PATH%`? To verify, in the failed build configuration, switch to the _Parameters_ tab and see what your value of `env.PATH` is.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure this out.  Its not just giving it the path to git.exe,  but the correct path.
If you do dir git.exe /s,  you will see its in a bunch of places.
I originally put it at  C:\Users\autobuild\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe.
This doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps what its looking for isn't there.
You need the path with cmd at the end.  In this case that was C:\Users\autobuild\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe.

This solved the problem.